# PublicKeyOutputs at Script Address vs ScriptOutputsAt Validator Hash vs valueLockedBy

Tags: plutus, context

Is the line
`scriptOutputsAt ownHash` equivalent to `pubKeyOutputsAt scrptAddress`?

More importantly, is `(valueLockedBy (scriptContextInfoTx ctx) ownHash)` just the sum of the outputs at the script address? IE is it the same as

```
let values = pubKeyOutputsAt scptAddress (scriptContextInfoTx ctx) in fold values
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at source code of [scriptOutputsAt](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.html#scriptOutputsAt), [pubKeyOutputsAt](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.html#pubKeyOutputsAt) and [valueLockedBy](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/src/Plutus.V1.Ledger.Contexts.html#valueLockedBy) I think, that (correct me if I wrong):

1. One important think to note right away, is that `pubKeyOutputsAt` requires `PubKeyHash` as first argument, so `pubKeyOutputsAt scptAddress ...` won't type check, if script hash used as `scptAddress` (otherwise - naming is a bit misleading =) ). Script hash defines script address, and public key, which defines public key hash, [used to derive a Cardano wallet address](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/3853/5017).
2. `scriptOutputsAt ownHash` *is not* equivalent to `pubKeyOutputsAt pubKeyHash` (note: `pubKeyHashs` for `pubKeyOutputsAt`, not `scptAddress`). `pubKeyOutputsAt` is `values paid to a public key address by a pending transaction` (when/if transaction succeeds). `scriptOutputsAt` is basically the same, but for scripts - values paid to a script address (defined by hash) by current transaction. So `scriptOutputsAt ownHash` will get you `Value` that *will* be paid to the current script (the script that does current validation) when transaction succeeds.
3. `valueLockedBy` uses `scriptOutputsAt` under the hood, applying one extra step to accumulate total `Value` (i.e. go from `[(DatumHash, Value)]` to just `Value` summing values from list). So it will give you total `Value` that *will* be paid to a script (and locked by that script). So `valueLockedBy (scriptContextInfoTx ctx) ownHash` is *not* the total `Value` of UTxOs that currently locked by the current script, but total `Value` of UTxOs which *will* be produced by this transaction and *will* be locked at the current script when transaction succeeds.
4. So, `(valueLockedBy (scriptContextInfoTx ctx) ownHash)` and `fold $ pubKeyOutputsAt pubKeyHash (scriptContextInfoTx ctx)` are not the same in principle, as former uses script hash, and latter - public key hash , giving value for different kinds of addresses.

Comment: Yes in my example scptAddress is the PubKeyHash associated with the script. Sorry if this was misleading. But essentially, in point 4 you are saying that the types of parameters differ, but they both do return the same result correct?